# Python requests headers not being set properly

Tags: python, header, python-requests

I'm having some trouble using Python requests. Here's my code:

```
fields={
    "fields":{
        "field1":{"test": "test"},
        "field2": "test",
        "field3":{"test": "test"}
    }
}

try:
    results = requests.post(
        "http://www.fakenotrealatall.com",
        data=json.dumps(fields),
        headers={"content-type": "application/json"}
    )

    print results.headers['content-type']

    return stuff
```

When I run it, I get a 415 error, and the print statement shows that the content-type is "text/html;charset=utf-8".

Why isn't it being set as "application/json"?

Comment: I've used code similar to yours and it's still working today.  But my implementation uses ``'Content-Type': "application/json;encoding='utf-8'"``.  Try it and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Gave that a shot, still no dice...

Comment: You're printing the content-type from the HTTP response not the one in your header you set in the request.  So the content-type you're printing will be what ever ``http://www.fakenotrealatall.com`` set it as, which in this case is ``text/html;charset=utf-8``.

Answer (score 3):

You got a 415 error because the server at "http://www.fakenotrealatall.com" returned a 415 error. According to [the HTTP standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.16), that means

> > The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Apparently, the folks at www.fakenotrealatall.com don't like JSON.

The value of `results.headers['content-type']` is "text/html" because, again, that is what the server returned. Remember, this is the type of the data returned to you, **not** the type of the data you sent. To see this, try:

```
print results.headers['content-type']
print results.request.headers['content-type']
```

Notice how the *request* has a JSON type, but the *response* is in HTML.

Finally, to see how this is all supposed to work, try POSTing to a site that *will* accept JSON, like http://httpbin.org :

```
import requests
import json

fields={
    "fields":{
        "field1":{"test": "test"},
        "field2": "test",
        "field3":{"test": "test"}
    }
}

results = requests.post(
        "http://httpbin.org/post",
        data=json.dumps(fields),
        headers={"content-type": "application/json"}
    )

print results.status_code, results.reason
print results.headers['content-type']
print results.request.headers['content-type']
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create headers use single quotes.

```
headers = {'content-type':'application/json', 'custom-header':'custom value'}
```